# Can OracleBulkCopy move data from my process address space to a table?

Tags: c#, oracle, etl, bulkinsert, odp.net

I'm hoping to speed up some large scale ETL operations, that read and transform a bunch of stuff from strangely formatted flat files and an even stranger XML datastore, then insert many records into an Oracle dbms.  I'm using ODP.NET 11g in C# / dotnet 4.

The OracleBulkCopy class seems like a good thing to try.  The thing is, it wants to read its data from an IDataReader instance or an array of IDataRecord instances ( i.e. a resultset of some other dbms query).

Is there a straightforward way to wrap my data rows in an IDataReader or an array of IDataRecord classes, in memory so I can push them into OracleBulkCopy?

The examples I've found show data migration from one dbms to another. But, I'm trying to avoid writing these items one-by-one to a dbms so I can then bulk load them.  I'd rather use the IDataReader equivalent of a memory stream.  Thanks.

Comment: Years on, a comment on my own question. Looks like there's an open-source project doing this sort of thing: https://github.com/HeadspringLabs/bulk-writer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I was using Link2Sql and found problems in the performance. I have found a solution using reflection and extension methods, where I read the column data out of the ColumnAttribute.

```
public static void Insert<T>(this OracleBulkCopy copy, IEnumerable<T> entities)
    where T : class
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var columnNames = new List<string>();
    var columnPropertyNames = new List<string>();
    foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
    {
        var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propertyInfo, typeof(ColumnAttribute)) as ColumnAttribute;
        if (attribute != null)
        {
            columnNames.Add(attribute.Name);
            columnPropertyNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    copy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
    foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
    {
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(columnName, columnName);
    }

    var table = new DataTable(copy.DestinationTableName);

    foreach (var columnMapping in copy.ColumnMappings)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(((OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping)columnMapping).DestinationColumn);
    }

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.Count; i++)
        {
            var value = typeof (T).GetProperty(columnPropertyNames[i]).GetValue(entity, null);
            if (value is DateTime)
                value = new OracleDate((DateTime) value);
            row[columnNames[i]] = value;
        }

        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    copy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

The Entity looks like:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
  [Column(Name = "Id")]
  public string Id { get; set; }
  //more columns
}
```

Using it is as easy as:

```
using (var connection = CreateDbConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var copy = new OracleBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        copy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        copy.BulkCopyTimeout = DefaultTimeoutInSeconds;
        copy.BatchSize = BatchSize;
        copy.Insert(entities);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should note though that OracleBulkCopy suffers from a memory leak when BatchSize is smaller than the number of rows being inserted. You should either do the batching yourself (in the extension method) or change the BatchSize to equal the number of rows (in the extension method). I once reached ~2GB of RAM running a demo of 100,000 rows with a 50,000 BatchSize in a loop ~200 times.

Answer (score 2):

You could also create an "entity reader", where would be more "memory friendly".
And let me remind you that reflection is really slow, so, maybe you should think of using an lambda expression solution, where it would build and compile all the property getters and then, for each line, just call it.

I didn't tested because i dont have oracle 11g :(
Something like this:

```
public static class GetterGenerator<T>
    {
        private readonly static Type type = typeof(T);
        private readonly static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> getters = Generate();
        private readonly static PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties().ToArray();
        private static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> Generate()
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties().ToArray();
            int propertiesLength = properties.Length;

            var props = new Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>>(propertiesLength);

            for (int i = 0; i < propertiesLength; i++)
            {
                ParameterExpression p = LambdaExpression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");
                LambdaExpression l = LambdaExpression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(
                    LambdaExpression.Convert(
                        LambdaExpression.Property(p, properties[i]), typeof(object)
                    ), p);
                props.Add(properties[i].Name, l.Compile() as Func<T, object>);
            }

            return props;
        }
        public static Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> GettersDictionary
        {
            get { return getters; }
        }
        public static Func<T, object>[] Getters
        {
            get { return getters.Values.ToArray(); }
        }
        public static PropertyInfo[] Properties 
        {
            get { return properties;}
        }
    }
    public class EntityReader<T> : IDataReader
    {
        private Func<T, object>[] getters = GetterGenerator<T>.Getters;
        private Dictionary<string, Func<T, object>> gettersDictionary = GetterGenerator<T>.GettersDictionary;
        private PropertyInfo[] properties = GetterGenerator<T>.Properties;

        private IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
        private int affected = 0;

        public EntityReader(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
        }

        #region IDataReader Members

        public void Close()
        {
        }

        public int Depth
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }

        public DataTable GetSchemaTable()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool IsClosed
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public bool NextResult()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool Read()
        {
            bool read = enumerator.MoveNext();
            if (read)
                affected++;
            return read;
        }

        public int RecordsAffected
        {
            get { return affected; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            properties = null;
            getters = null;
            gettersDictionary = null;
            enumerator = null;
            affected = 0;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDataRecord Members

        public int FieldCount
        {
            get { return getters.Length; }
        }
        private Y GetValue<Y>(int i)
        {
            try
            {
                return (Y)GetValue(i);
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException)
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException(string.Format("Invalid cast from '{0}' to '{1}'", GetFieldType(i), typeof(Y)));
            }
        }

        public bool GetBoolean(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<bool>(i);
        }

        public byte GetByte(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<byte>(i);
        }

        public long GetBytes(int i, long fieldOffset, byte[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public char GetChar(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<char>(i);
        }

        public long GetChars(int i, long fieldoffset, char[] buffer, int bufferoffset, int length)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public IDataReader GetData(int i)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string GetDataTypeName(int i)
        {
            return GetFieldType(i).Name;
        }

        public DateTime GetDateTime(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<DateTime>(i);
        }

        public decimal GetDecimal(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<decimal>(i);
        }

        public double GetDouble(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<double>(i);
        }

        public Type GetFieldType(int i)
        {
            return properties[i].PropertyType;
        }

        public float GetFloat(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<float>(i);
        }

        public Guid GetGuid(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<Guid>(i);
        }

        public short GetInt16(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<short>(i);
        }

        public int GetInt32(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<int>(i);
        }

        public long GetInt64(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<long>(i);
        }

        public string GetName(int i)
        {
            return properties[i].Name;
        }

        public int GetOrdinal(string name)
        {
            bool found = false;
            int i = 0;
            int propertiesLength = properties.Length;
            while (!found && i < propertiesLength)
                found = properties[i++].Name == name;
            if (!found)
                i = -1;
            return i;
        }

        public string GetString(int i)
        {
            return GetValue<string>(i);
        }

        public object GetValue(int i)
        {
            return getters[i](enumerator.Current);
        }

        public int GetValues(object[] values)
        {
            int length = Math.Min(values.Length, getters.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                values[i] = getters[i](enumerator.Current);
            return length;
        }

        public bool IsDBNull(int i)
        {
            return GetValue(i) == null;
        }

        public object this[string name]
        {
            get { return GetValue(GetOrdinal(name)); }
        }

        public object this[int i]
        {
            get { return GetValue(i); }
        }

        #endregion
    }
    public static void Insert<T>(this OracleBulkCopy copy, IEnumerable<T> entities, Dictionary<string, string> ColumnMap) 
        where T : class
    {
        copy.ColumnMappings.Clear();
        foreach (var map in ColumnMap)
            copy.ColumnMappings.Add(map.Key, map.Value);

        IDataReader reader = new EntityReader<T>(entities);
        copy.WriteToServer(reader);
    }
```